# Copy range of rows to named sheet

Tags: excel, vba, loops

The code below will create a new sheet for each cell in column A. The second module will copy all rows that have a specific value in column A to a specific destination.

I created this so each work order number gets its own sheet and all rows with that work order number is copied over to the sheet named that work order number.

The issue is there are 604 unique work order numbers and I have to edit the second module for each work order in order for it to work.

Is there some way I could have it loop through all the values in column A and maybe compare it to a set variable and then copy the rows to the sheet that has that work order number? I don't know how to make the destination sheet be whatever new value is found in column A.

I'm new to VBA, so this question probably doesn't make much sense. And yes I have seen code for creating and naming a sheet based on each new work order in one module but it generally won't compile so I split the process out to 2 modules.

Anyway, to better understand what I mean: say column A has 4 rows for work order number 1234. I'd need the macro to copy all 4 rows for 1234 into the sheet that is named 1234. Then move on to the next work order number. 
The range it is checking for work orders in is A2:A39986, but the full range is A2:F39986.

Thank you for your time.

```
Option Explicit

Sub parse_data()
   Dim xRCount As Long
   Dim xSht As Worksheet
   Dim xNSht As Worksheet
   Dim I As Long
   Dim xTRow As Integer
   Dim xCol As New Collection
   Dim xTitle As String
   Dim xSUpdate As Boolean
   Set xSht = ActiveSheet
   On Error Resume Next
   xRCount = xSht.Cells(xSht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
   xTitle = "A60:A604"
   xTRow = xSht.Range(xTitle).Cells(1).Row
   For I = 2 To xRCount
     Call xCol.Add(xSht.Cells(I, 1).Text, xSht.Cells(I, 1).Text)
   Next
   xSUpdate = Application.ScreenUpdating
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   For I = 1 To xCol.Count
      Call xSht.Range(xTitle).AutoFilter(1, CStr(xCol.Item(I)))
      Set xNSht = Nothing
      Set xNSht = Worksheets(CStr(xCol.Item(I)))
      If xNSht Is Nothing Then
         Set xNSht = Worksheets.Add(, Sheets(Sheets.Count))
         xNSht.Name = CStr(xCol.Item(I))
      Else
         xNSht.Move , Sheets(Sheets.Count)
      End If
      xSht.Range("A" & xTRow & xRCount).EntireRow.Copy xNSht.Range("A60")
      xNSht.Columns.AutoFit
    Next
    xSht.AutoFilterMode = False
    xSht.Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = xSUpdate


End Sub
```

and the module that copies data to a specific destination:

```
    Sub CopyColumnOver()

    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Dim wsDestin As Worksheet
    Dim lngDestinRow As Long
    Dim rngSource As Range
    Dim rngCel As Range

    Set wsSource = Sheets("Sheet1")     'Edit "Sheet1" to your source sheet name
    Set wsDestin = Sheets("11556")

    With wsSource
        'Following line assumes column headers in Source worksheet so starts at row2
        Set rngSource = .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    End With

    For Each rngCel In rngSource
        If rngCel.Value = "11556" Then
            With wsDestin
                'Following line assumes column headers in Destination worksheet
                lngDestinRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
                rngCel.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=wsDestin.Cells(lngDestinRow, "A")
            End With
        End If
    Next rngCel

End Sub
```

Comment: Pass the values you find as arguments to the sub that is copying to a new sheet and put that into ```sheets()```. You will need to check to see if the sheet exists and if not then create it.

Comment: You're creating over 600 sheets in a workbook, duplicating the data from one sheet??? Why? What are you trying to achieve? There's got to be a better way.

Comment: I'm going to do analysis of data based on each work order so it's important that all the data is separated out. I will have to aggregate operations and calculate average time to complete and then insert results in to final report.